# Java: Apache Tika: unexpected runtimeexception when extracting text from .doc file. The file opens without any error in MSWord

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika

I have used TikaParser to extract plain text from '.doc' files

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ContentHandler handler = new ToHTMLContentHandler();
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    FileInputStream content = new FileInputStream("file.doc");
    parser.parse(content, handler, metadata, context);
    System.out.println(handler.toString());

    String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
    for (String name : metadataNames) {
        System.out.println(name + " : " + metadata.get(name));
    }

    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("file.doc.txt");
    outStream.write(handler.toString().getBytes());
    outStream.close();
    content.close();
}
```

This is working for most of the files but for a specific file, it is throwing the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@7c417213
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:282)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
at com.goarya.app.resumestorage.migration.TikaParser.main(TikaParser.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The end (7161) must not be before the start (7162)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range.sanityCheckStartEnd(Range.java:208)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range.<init>(Range.java:194)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph.<init>(Paragraph.java:165)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph.newParagraph(Paragraph.java:144)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range.getParagraph(Range.java:766)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor.getParagraphText(WordExtractor.java:168)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor.getMainTextboxText(WordExtractor.java:145)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:183)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:169)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:130)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
... 3 more
```

The doc file when opened in Microsoft Word shows no error.

Also, in C# using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` gives plain text.

How do I overcome this issue using Apache Tika?

Edit: adding [sample doc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vwGeTfv6vHRGw0Tk0xc2Z0aEU/view?usp=sharing) for this scenario

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using?

Comment: I'm using tika version 1.14

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. The tika parser is throwing the same exception for few files. Any Solution @MouliKalakota

Answer (score -1):

I am using tika cote1.2 jar and my program has been run successfully with the following code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToHTMLContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Exmple2 {
     public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException,TikaException, SAXException {

         ToHTMLContentHandler handler = new ToHTMLContentHandler();
            AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

            FileInputStream content = new FileInputStream("/home/ist/FTRDocuments/taableDis.docx");
            parser.parse(content, handler, metadata, context);
            System.out.println(handler.toString());

            String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
            for (String name : metadataNames) {
                System.out.println(name + " : " + metadata.get(name));
            }

            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/ist/file.doc.txt");
            outStream.write(handler.toString().getBytes());
            outStream.close();
            content.close();
     }


}
```

The only thing  change with tika1.2 is ToHTMLContentHandler where you are using  ContentHandler.

Comment: It is working for most of the documents except for the documents that are similar to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vwGeTfv6vHRGw0Tk0xc2Z0aEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i thought you have been facing the problem for all documents.

Comment: please share the solution, if you've found a way around.